# How does EntityFramework attribute InverseProperty works?

Tags: entity-framework, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I'm working with WebMatrix and EntityFramework.

In my database I have a user table, in our business logic a user can create or update the content of another table, so my user class in my model is like this:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50), MinLength(5), Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(16), MinLength(8), Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50), Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50), Required]
    public string LasName1{ get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50), Required]
    public string LasName2{ get; set; }

    public string token { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<Device> CreatedDevices {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("UpdatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<Device> UpdatedDevices {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<Cluster> CreatedClusters {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("UpdatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<Cluster> UpdatedClusters {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<Region> CreatedRegions {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("UpdatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<Region> UpdatedRegions {get; set;}
}
```

For exampl,e my Region class looks like this:

```
[Table("Regions")]
public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50), MinLength(5), Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cluster> Clusters { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }

    public Usuario CreatedBy { get; set; } 

    public Usuario UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

This creates the necessary relationships between the entities in the database. Now comes my main doubt, in my Cluster table there's a CreatedBy_UserId, so when I'm doing the insert or update of an entry in the table, do I have to pass a User object? I'm saying something like this

```
Cluster cluster = new Cluster()
{
   RegionId = regionId,
   CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime,
   UpdatedDateTime = updatedDateTime,
   CreatedBy = currentUser,
   UpdatedBy = currentUser
};
```

Or how do I pass an int representing the foreign key to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a foreign key property in your model, then yes, you need to set the navigation properties to establish a relationship. You only must make sure that `currentUser` is attached to the context - by loading it from the DB or attaching manually. Otherwise EF would also create new users. An example is this:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Users.Attach(currentUser);
    Cluster cluster = new Cluster()
    {
        RegionId = regionId,
        CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime,
        UpdatedDateTime = updatedDateTime,
        CreatedBy = currentUser,
        UpdatedBy = currentUser
    };
    context.Clusters.Add(cluster);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

`SaveChanges` will create an `INSERT` statement with the correct foreign key values (equal to `currentUser.UserId`) set.

Comment: sorry I'm just starting to work on EF, in what kind of situations should I use the Attach method? If the call to Attach would be removed, why would EF create new users? 
Also a big question, if I were to delete an entry, my delete method receives an int id, then queries for the entry in the following manner `Cluster cluster = (from c in db.Clusters where c.ClusterId == id select c).FirstOrDefault();` and then removes it like this `db.Clusters.Remove(cluster); db.SaveChanges();`, given that I have Inverse Properties, will this approach to delete the entries work?

Comment: @UrielArvizu: By calling `Attach` you tell EF that the entity already exists in the DB. (It has the same effect as loading the entity from the DB, without the actual roundtrip to the DB.) When you call `Add` for the `cluster` EF checks the cluster *and all related entities* if they are attached. If not, it assumes that it has to insert the related entities as well. If it is attached it just sets the FK to the existing user row. Your approach to delete the cluster should work, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much, can I contact you if I present any doubts related to EF? I'm trying to learn and it would be great if I could get direct answers. Thanks again.